# Angular + angularAMD, load a controller before bootstrapping the app

Tags: angularjs, amd

First of all, thanks for this great plugin! (to the author of angularAMD)

I have some troubles. I have all modules loaded with ngAMD but two are inside my index.html because are templates and I'm including this way:

```
 <div ng-include="'views/header.html'"></div>
```

header.html uses HeaderCtrl but I have no idea how load before angularAMD.bootstrap...

More code:

**header.coffee** that requires app

```
define ['app', 'bootstrap'], (app, bs) ->
  'use strict'

  app.controller 'HeaderCtrl', ($scope, $rootScope) ->
    $scope.searchText = "";

    $scope.updateSearch = -> 
      $rootScope.searchText = $scope.searchText;
```

**app.coffee**

```
define ['angular', 'angularAMD'], (angular, angularAMD) ->
  'use strict'

  app = angular.module 'testsApp', [
    'ngRoute'
    'localization'
    'restangular'
  ]

  angularAMD.bootstrap app
  app
```

After bootstrapping app, ng tries to solve ng-include but HeaderCtrl is not loaded! This happens only with CTRL+F5 on page, it's a matter of loading time. I have no idea on how solve this. Any hint?

Comment: Are you still having problem?  If you do, setup a simple plunker and I will see what I can do to help.

Comment: @marcoseu : thanks. I've solved. I'll put the solution online ASAP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was `angularAMD.bootstrap app` position. I was bootstrapping before loading each dependencies.

I moved `angularAMD.bootsrapp` call after dep loading and all works now:

**bootstrap.coffee** (the application bootstrapper)

```
define [
  'app'
  'jquery'
  '_'
  'angularAMD'
  'ctrl/header'
  'ctrl/menu']
, (app, $, _, angularAMD) ->

  # bootstrapping all dependencies
  $.get "modules/modules.json", (deps) ->
    # converts all array items from DEP to module!DEP
    deps = _.map deps, (dep) ->
      "module!#{dep}"

    console.log JSON.stringify deps
    require deps, ->
      console.log "Dependencies loaded!"
      # I'll bootstrap angular only after each dependencies are loaded, this prevents many 'random' issues.
      angularAMD.bootstrap app
```

I hope this can help someone :)